# Django how to login after hitting post button?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am writing a twitter clone using Django framework. The home page has a form and a POST button. Upon hitting POST, I want to check if user is signed in. If not signed in, it will take user to login form. Once login is finished, the message will be saved to the database and homepage updated. I am at a loss of how to do it. My django methods are as follows

```
class MsgListView(ListView):
    model = coremodels.message
    template_name = "msg.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MsgListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = MsgForm()
        return context

    #@method_decorator(login_required(login_url=reverse('MsgListView')))
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                             
        print "Inside MsgListView post"
        view = MsgFormPost.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

class MsgFormPost(FormView, SingleObjectMixin ):
    form_class = MsgForm
    model = coremodels.message;

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        #    return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = None
        return super(MsgFormPost, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('MsgListView')

class MsgForm(forms.ModelForm):                                                                                                                           
    date_n_time = forms.DateTimeField(initial=date.today(), widget=HiddenInput())
    parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=coremodels.message.objects.none(),required=False,widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    text = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':1,'rows':3, 'id': 'msginput','oninput':"this.editor.update()"}))
    def is_valid(self):
        self.fields["parent"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=coremodels.message.objects.all(),required=False,widget=forms.HiddenInput())
        return super(MsgForm, self).is_valid()
    class Meta:
        model = coremodels.message
        fields = "__all__"
```

The problem is that login decorator ignores the POST parameters completely. 
I tried using django sessions, but it becomes complicated as then, I should save form during get request. How do I solve this?

The form itself is as follows

```
<form autocomplete="off" class=" message" name="post-box" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Ij1kmJuP84KdNIedcg3JnryvzaEFXk2q">
                <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="controls">

                    <div id="post-box-body">
                      <textarea name="text" id="tagsinput_id" oninput="this.editor.update()" class="input-block-level" rows="2" placeholder="Write message" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; height: 130px;"></textarea>

                    </div>
                    <div id="post-box-footer">  
                      <div class="pull-right">
                        <button data-pre-flight-text="Post" data-in-flight-text="Posting..." type="submit" class="btn btn-primary limited-access-aware">Post</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>

               <div class="form-group warning col-md-4  data-picker col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="/* width: 160px; */">
                   <!--<label for="exampleInputFile">Date n time</label>-->
                   <input class="form-control" id="id_date_n_time" name="date_n_time" type="hidden" value="2016-03-06">

               </div>
               <div class="form-group warning col-md-4">
                   <!--<label for="exampleInputFile">Parent</label>-->
                   <input class="form-control" id="id_parent" name="parent" type="hidden">

               </div>
```

Comment: What is the view method for your home page, which has the form?

Comment: The class based view for home page MsgListView. I have reproduced the code for it above.

Comment: Why are you using a ListView to display your form? You need to use a simple view (like FormView) to display your login form; and then a separate view for your home page which has the tweets. You are confusing yourself by combining them together. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) for a simple example on how to log a user in.

Comment: I am making a view in which I have both the form for inputting and listing of messages. Even in the case you suggested, I must first login and only then someone can type their message. I want the reverse. Let them type message first and then ask for login info(for increasing engagement). This is very similar to what is implemented in following webpage. http://askbot.org/en/questions/ask/

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I am talking about. I am saying, use one view to manage the login form, and another view to display the messages. In this view to display messages, you can have a form to write a message. One this form is submitted, your view checks if the user is logged in, if not, then redirects to the login view. It has nothing to do with what view comes "first".

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question,
Modify MsgListView's post function by adding session keys

```
#@method_decorator(login_required(login_url=reverse('MsgListView')))
#@method_decorator(login_required)
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print "Inside MsgListView post"

    if not request.user.is_authenticated(): 
        request.session['checkpoint'] = json.dumps(request.POST)
        request.session['post_after_login'] = True

        return redirect('user_login')

    view = MsgFormPost.as_view()
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Note that the decorator is commented out.

In user_login function(which serves login view), I take in username and password, authenticate user and then call login(). Once this is done, I retrieve session variables and post the information to MsgListView as shown below.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^login$', coreviews.user_login, name='user_login')
```

view.py:

```
def user_login(request):

if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("next") is not None:
    next_url = request.POST["next"]
elif request.method == 'GET' and request.GET.get("next") is not None:
    print "request.GET is ",request.GET
    print "request.GET.next is ",request.GET.get("next"),"raghu"
    next_url = request.GET["next"]
else:
    next_url = "/" #settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

# If the request is a HTTP POST, try to pull out the relevant information.
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            if request.session.get("post_after_login") == True:
                checkpoint = json.loads(request.session['checkpoint'])
                request.POST = checkpoint                                                                                                             
                view = MsgFormPost.as_view()
                request.session.pop('post_after_login')
                return view(request, None, **checkpoint)

            return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url,'/msg')
        else:
            # An inactive account was used - no logging in!
            return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled.")
            .
            .#Remaining logic
            .
```

This solution seems hacky but its working for now.